# Understanding LLVM IR linkage type internal?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

[LLVM IR Linkage Type](http://www.llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#linkage-types) introduce linkage type `internal`, but I don't understand the *STB_LOCAL* and *ELF* words.

What does this linkage type do extractly? And what's the difference between `private` and `internal` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ELF` or *Executable and Linkable Format* is a formal specification that allows your OS to correctly interpret binaries.

`STB_LOCAL` is the binding attribute in `ELF`  that qualifies a symbol as being local to an object file or translation unit.

A symbol table holds information related to a translation unit/module/program's symbolic definitions and references and is made up of multiple sections or sub tables e.g a symbol string table. See http://www.frascati.enea.it/documentation/tru6450/SUPPDOCS/OBJSPEC/DOCU_005.HTM

An object file is divided into sections (different from the symbol table sections) and every symbol table entry is *defined* in relation to some section.

`private` linkage is generally used for symbols associated with a *single* section. An example will be local function symbols. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter6-79797/index.html

The `internal` and `private` linkage types both mean the global value is only directly accessible by objects in the current module. Only thing is in the private case the value does will not show up in the symbol table.

Comment: What are the consequences if `in the private case the value does not show up in the local symbol table`?